# docker, ubuntu. Ошибка установки

Tags: ubuntu, docker, install

Для установки докера использую команду

```
sudo apt-get install -y docker-engin
```

Получаю результат: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интсрукцию инсталяции ипользовал с сайта https://www.8host.com/blog/ustanovka-i-ispolzovanie-docker-v-ubuntu-16-04/

Всё шло без проблем до этой команды.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: 1. пакет у вас уже установлен. 2. наблюдаемые ошибки относятся совсем к другим пакетам (они перечислены). удалите те, что вам не нужны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать [официальную инструкцию по установке](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) для Ubuntu

Начиная с самого начала в вашем вопросе команда - `apt-get install docker-engine`

А в официальном руководстве **вся работа начинается с удаления  устаревших пакетов** - `sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io`. Следуете официальной инструкции (проверено на множестве разных OS) и всё будет работать как надо.

Самый простой официальный вариант установки докер:

```
$ curl -fsSL get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
$ sudo sh get-docker.sh
```

Не усложняйте себе жизнь!